# AWS target group randomly deregistering target

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I have an instance registered to a target group but it randomly will deregister and I have to go in and register the instance to the target group. This causes a 503 to be returned. Any idea why it keeps getting deregistered? The instances are behind and ALB.

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, "instances" are being removed from the target group and not the "target group" being removed from the ALB? Have a look at your healthcheck parameters and see if they're failing... there are metrics/graphs that should line up if so

Comment: @John yes the instance is being removed from the target group. The "target group" is still connected to the ALB. Once I register the instance again, everything works fine. Could you clarify what you mean by " healthcheck parameters"?

Comment: Your target groups have healthchecks that are used to indicate if an instance is healthy and if the ALB should send traffic to it.
Docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/target-group-health-checks.html

Comment: @John yes, I have a health check which hits my /api/healthcheck endpoint. But I'm not sure how I can use this to debug. All I know so far is that the instance was deregistered so no metrics were available during that period of which it was not registered.

Comment: If it's not healthchecks the only other thing I can think of would be deployment logic that is removing an instance while being updated and not re-attaching it for some reason. Edit: cloudwatch has metrics for target groups and when instances are deemed unhealthy (IE: failed healthchecks) and also instance count metrics (point in time instance was removed)

Comment: @John I haven't deployed or updated the instance, it was working fine for the past few days and randomly gets deregistered. I have attached some metrics from the target group monitoring section, if that is of any use. I will look at cloud watch now and see if I can spot something.

Comment: I would suggest looking at the ec2 metrics at the times your instances were dropped and also your logs on your instance. Also, to troubleshoot further you could activate "Cloud Trail" to see if any requests to the AWS API is detaching your instance and from what API account/role is doing so

Comment: Please tell us the status of health checks!

Comment: Did you find a solution or did it get resolved by itself after some time?